# Javascript OR on if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using the following line to validate a Credit Card form, I want to return false IF the length of the CVV is not equal to 3 OR 4.

```
var x = document.forms["booking"]["cvv"].value;

if ( x.length != 3 || x.length != 4) {
   alert("Please Enter a Valid CVV Number");
   return false;
}
```

However, when I input a 3 or 4 digit number I am returned false instead of true. I am not sure if my OR statement is valid or correct.

It is worth mentioning that if I only validate for length equals 3 the form returns true.

Comment: How about `if (x.length < 3 || x.length > 4)`

Comment: It's the [same issue as I answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307689/do-while-conditions-isnt-stopping-loop-java/20307704#20307704) (the language is irrelevant in this case). Hopefully seeing how to rewrite the conditional to an equivalent form makes things more clear.

Comment: 3 is "not 4", and 4 is "not 3", so "not 3" or "not 4" is a tautology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean if the length is not 3 AND not 4:

```
if ( x.length != 3 && x.length != 4) {
   alert("Please Enter a Valid CVV Number");
   return false;
}
```

The logic is somewhat reversed when doing " **not** equals " something, as not 3 OR not 4 is never true, as it's always **not** one or the other