# Java while loop works with a netbean error

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, equals

I'm trying to implement a program that needs a loop:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String word= scan.next().toLowerCase();
while !(word.equals("mot1") || word.equals("mot2") || word.equals("motmot") || word.equals("motmotmot") ){
word= word.next().toLowerCase();
}
```

it works, though, it underlines the while condition with the red error wavelet!!

the error is shown on the left in the margin with an exclamation mark (!) and says 
'(' expexted
')' expected

so i've been trying to put bracket in all senses, the only time it would take the wavelet off is the case when it does not work anymore, and there is an infinite loop!

I don't know why?

Cheers

ADDition:

When the wavelet is off but won't do what intended but the logic is here:

```
 String word= scan.next().toLowerCase();
           while (!word.equals("onetime") || !word.equals("daily") || !word.equals("weekly") || !word.equals("monthly") ){

}
```

Comment: Please review java `while` loop syntax. Where are you putting the `!`?

Comment: How does it work when it can't compile?

Comment: yes but it works, like this! it compiles and do exactly what I want, the problem is that Netbean shows an error where there is none.

Comment: @Rsmusic your ! needs to be inside your ()

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Would you please disclose the full code for the loop you are building.

Comment: So yes the problem was that Netbean does not like Exclamation mark out of brackets! I could not find the right logic with the other way around
thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong and it suffers from [the same issue as I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307689/do-while-conditions-isnt-stopping-loop-java/20307704#20307704).

That is,

```
!x || !y || !z
```

is equivalent to (by [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws))

```
!(x && y && z)
```

Since (in this case), x, y and z can *never all be true* at the same time the result is:

```
!(false) -> true
```

---

The correct logic for this is then, `!(x || y || z)` or, applying the rule again, `!x && !y && !z`.

---

In any case, I would recommend writing it using a function that utilizes the logic presented above ..

```
while (!validChoice(word)) {
    // ..
}

boolean validChoice (String word) {
    return word.equals(..) || word.equals(..) ..;
}
```

.. as it's how I keep things straight in my head.

Comment: I believe the nature of his problem is related to the format of his code in general. The "while" loop is executed in the wrong fashion. "While (conditions)" should include the code for the execution and break when condition is met using break; statement - unless do/while loop is introduced.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic That's one way to view it. However, I personally very rarely use `break` and find that the *reason* for why the loop never terminates need to be understood.

Comment: Ok thank you, how do you develop !(x || y || z) then?

Comment: @Rsmusic Changing it to that would work; I would also move the logic to a function (for "self documenting code"), but that needs not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to the format of your code. The syntax assigned is not correct.

```
String word;

while (!word.equals("onetime") || !word.equals("daily") || !word.equals("weekly") || !word.equals("monthly") ){
    word = input.next();
    // do something;
}
```