# C syntax - I need to make a simple if branch to detect a specific condition

Tags: c, filter, branch

I have an 8 bits variable and I need to detect if that variable contains another value different of 'S' or 'G'.

I try the following code

```
if(XType!='S' || XType!='G')
 {
   Reload();
 }
```

As I realize now, that didn't work. :(

I'm not allowed to use any library it must be resolved logically cause is very basic C compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307689/do-while-conditions-isnt-stopping-loop-java/20307704#20307704 - different language and values, same logic issue. It's important to be able to apply [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) trivially - or, at least it helps me reason about logical conditions better.

Comment: Thanks, good to know this, until a couple of minutes ago I thought that Morgan was a pirate. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(XType!='S' || XType!='G')
```

will always evaluate true.  (if `XType` is `'G'` then `XType!='S'` will be true; anything else will mean that `XType!='G'` will be true.  Logical OR `||` will evaluate true if at least one of its inputs is true so your condition will always be true.)

Try using logical AND `&&` instead.  This only evaluates true if both inputs are true.

```
if(XType!='S' && XType!='G')
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer; I'm debugging now and seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if(XType!='S' && XType!='G')
 {
   Reload();
 }
```

because

```
if(XType!='S' || XType!='G')
```

returns always true

Comment: Thanks! Two people answered correctly. How I must to proceed? I think I can mark just one answer as the right one, but both are ok.

Comment: @E_Blue Choose whichever answer helped you most or seems most useful for future readers of the question.  See [this previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for some details.