# if (($orgname != $row['org1']) or ($orgname != $row['org2']))

Tags: php

I need to compare the two rows in my database but it is not working.. Here is my codes.. Hope you can help me..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (($orgname != $row['org1']) or ($orgname != $row['org2'])){
    echo "<font size = 2><font color='red'>You are not a member of the organization</font>";}
}
```

Comment: Your condition is always true, use `&&` instead of `or`

Comment: The code you have says that $orgname must be the same in both the values org1 and org2 ... is this what you really want?

Comment: Yes! that's what i want

Comment: Different language, but [same fundamental issue as I've answered previously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20307704/2864740) - just understand De Morgan's law, as it helps to rewrite (and thus verify) logical conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it is easier to understand:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ( !($orgname == $row['org1'] && $orgname == $row['org2']) ){
         echo "<font size = 2><font color='red'>You are not a member of the organization</font>";
    }
}
```

Edited after i read @nico19 message

Comment: When you find a condition that is difficult to write just try to invert it and put a ! in front, usually it helps a lot. ;)

Comment: Ok sir. I'll take note of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (($orgname != $row['org1']) && ($orgname != $row['org2'])){
    echo "<font size = 2><font color='red'>You are not a member of the organization</font>";}
}
```

You need `&& AND` condition here instead of `|| OR`